# Spreading sequence and processing gain

Tags: digital-communications

The following has been mentioned regarding spreading using a 32 chip sequence

*32x spreading contributes a theoretical 15 dB gain to the link budget,*

I have no clue, why so? Are we referring to the processing gain?

I thought spreading was  performed to mitigate narrow band noise and ISI.

Comment: The "15 dB" number comes from the fact that $15 \approx 10 \log_{10}(32)$. Processing gain in the context of direct-sequence spread spectrum signals comes during the despreading process; the bandwidth of the despread signal is 32 times smaller than the spread signal, hence the gain.

Comment: Isnt the processing gain $G$ due to the fact, we suppressed the interference by $G$?

Comment: That's one way to look at it. The despreading process also *spreads* any narrowband interference, pushing a lot of its energy out of the band of the despread signal.